# How to merge tables with different number of columns in DolphinDB?

Tags: union-all, dolphindb

I want to join tables with different number of columns into a single table. Is there a more efficient way to do this, apart from using iterative appending via a `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unionAll`.

```
t1 = table(take(1, 10) as id, rand(`a`b`c , 10) as name)
t2 = table(take(1, 10) as id, rand(`a`b`f , 10) as name, rand(10.0, 10) as val)
t3 = table(take(1, 10) as id, rand(`a`d`e , 10) as name)

unionAll([t1,t2,t3], false, byColName=true)
```